# Wraping text in a bounded datagridview column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview populated by a dataset from a db. One of the columns contains a long text. I would link to show in cell only a few characters and when user clicks on it a popup window to be shown containg the entire text. (c#, sql server)

Is there an example you can show me how I can do this? or any better ideas on how to display text?

Comment: The default behavior of DataGridViewTextBoxColumn is exactly the same that you want, it shows the a few characters that fill the available space and once the mouse is hovered, it shows the full text

Answer (score 0):

You can add an Event to your Datagridview called: CellClick

In that event you can initialize a new form. and you can pass the complete string to the form

Somethiing like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.ColumnIndex == YOUR_DESIRED_COLUMN)
     {
         string text = VALUE_TO_PASS_ON;
         Form1 frm = new Form1( text);
         frm.Show();
     }
}
```